# How to get proper Validation on SpringBoot RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I have the below Controller code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/perf")
@Validated
public class PerfController {

    private final AnalyticsRepository analyticsRepository;

    public PerfController(AnalyticsRepository analyticsRepository) {
        this.analyticsRepository = analyticsRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Integer getData(@Valid @RequestParam(name = "time") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") String time) {
        System.out.println("> time: " + time);
```

However, the **date time format is not being checked/validated**. On passing invalid strings, **no exceptions get thrown**.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no validation being made because your parameter is a `String`, so Spring is treating as `String`.

The annotation `@DateTimeFormat` is used to declare to Spring the parameter should be treated as Date.

So, you should change `time` to be `Date` and not a `String`